# mediapipeUnityPlugin Mapping 3d coordinates with unity's human like avatar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapping, mediapipe, fbx

here is fbx model body bones [image]

and this is mediapipeUnityPlugin 33 point information
[image]

i want to motion tracking using this skeleton
[image]